# Are laptops currently allowed in carry-on luggage from Europe to the US?

Tags: air-travel, usa, europe, regulations

I've heard conflicting news stories and hearsay regarding the topic: Can I take a laptop (and also a digital SLR camera with a lithium rechargeable battery) as carry-on luggage on a flight from mainland Europe to the US? Is this policy expected to change in the next few weeks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: Yes.  This isn't really in question.  Laptops and Lithium batteries are allowed (sometimes required) as carry-ons.  You will have to check with the airline you are flying as each airline and/or regulatory authority can have slightly different rules.

Q2: Sorry, this question cannot be answered.  My estimation though is no.  We will only know for sure when a change is announced.  Update:  That Answer is now NO because no change has been announced.  However, it can happen at any time, though unlikely.

Comment: Please provide references for this.

Comment: "This isn't really in question." - well, it [certainly *was* in question only recently](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/05/10/business/us-may-ban-laptops-on-all-flights-from-europe.html).

Comment: Downvote totally unwarranted, wrong and unhelpful.  There is *nothing* wrong with this answer.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Laptops are allowed, *this is not in question in any way.*  Whether or not it will change is not answerable.  The answer is 100% correct.  Any downvotes are totally wrong.

Comment: @Johns-305: Please read my source, or search for yourself. This has widely been reported about. A ban on laptops as cabin luggage on flights from Europe to the U.S. was absolutely mentioned as a possible next step by the U.S. side until very few weeks ago. (With that said, I did not downvote, as the claim "This isn't really in question." is only a tangential remark in the answer.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think you're misunderstanding. It's not in question that it is currently 100% allowed to bring a laptop in hand luggage from Europe to the US. What IS in question is answered in "Q2" - the fact that this might well change in the future.

Comment: @Muzer: I understand the phrase "in question" the way it is, for example, defined by [OED (meaning 2, based on grammatical context)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/question), as a synonym for "in doubt". With publicly announced plans for a possible ban on laptops in hand luggage from Europe to the US, the policy that laptops are allowed in hand luggage was thus under reconsideration, in doubt, or, expressed differently, "in question".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Indeed, but the fact that you can currently take laptops on Europe-US planes isn't in any doubt. What IS in doubt is whether or not that is likely to continue to be the case. Taken alone I guess Q1 would be a little confusing, but with both paragraphs together I don't really see any ambiguity. Perhaps this does make it clear that the answer should be rephrased, though ;)

Comment: @Muzer: It seems the source of the misunderstanding is then that to me, having concrete clues that the current policy of allowing laptops as carry-on on flights from Europe to the US may be changed in the near future seems synonymous to saying that the current policy is in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Which airline are you flying? If you're flying direct from Europe to the US - then you should not be worrying about it - Unless you're flying from U.K. 
If you have a layover elsewhere it can be a problem (for instance if you're connecting in Istanbul via Turkish Airlines)

Comment: Why do you have to worry about it if you're flying from the UK?